# Trying to run jquery taggd plugin

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get working example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nlatin/36zya6bu with taggd jQuery plugin([link](https://timseverien.com/projects/taggd/)).
Can someone get this running?

Part of the code:

```
    var options = {
  align: {
    y: 'bottom'
  },

  offset: {
    top: -35
  },

  handlers: {
    mouseenter: 'show',
    mouseleave: 'hide'
  }
});

var data = [
  // pixel-based coordinates
  { x: 200,  y: 220,  text: 'Test'   },

  // 0-1 coordinates
  { x: 0.431, y: 0.33, text: 'Test2'   },
  { x: 0.468, y: 0.28, text: 'Test3' }
]);

$(window).load(function () {
    $('.taggd').taggd(options, data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Both variables end with a **closing parenthese** (`)`).

Earlier today I became aware there are some syntax errors on the documentation page. This code seems to be a direct copy of that code.

I am working on it, and the syntax errors on the page will be removed today :)